# Firefox & Chrome - different behavior for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I added one youtube video on my site (for e.g. `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QE5KOfjKLy0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` )

And using the extension for Firefox I can **get url of the youtube embed** video **when** I **middle click on title of the video or "youtube button"** (see screenshot below).

I don't why but it works and I can see the url of video in "browser console" (ctrl+shift+j for Firefox).

But Chromium-browsers has different behavior, it only works for simple url on current pages (`<a href="...">...</a>`), not url from `iframe`.

It would be great if Chrome can do the same.

Does anybody know why it's different for Firefox and Chrome?

Here content script (for Firefox and Chromium):

```
(function (undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var YoutubeExtActions = {
        linkClickListener : function(e) {
            if(e.button === 1) {
                var link = $(e.target).closest('a');    
                if(link.length && link.attr('href') !== '#') {
                    var url = link[0].href;
                    if(url.match(/youtube.com\/watch/i) || url.match(/youtube.com\/embed/i)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        console.log("you got it: " + url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
window.addEventListener("click",YoutubeExtActions.linkClickListener,false);
})();
```

That JS in Chrome works only for common links (not from iframes)

manifest.json:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "description": "chromium youtube iframe get url",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "chromium youtube iframe get url",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have content scripts autoinserted in iframes add `"all_frames": true` in manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": .................,
  "matches": .................,
  "all_frames": true
} ],
```

Documentation:

- [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)
- [Debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) - this tool is tremendously helpful.